# Passing text string with new lines through GET is breaking my redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, get

I'm submitting a form that uses javascript to pass a value through GET - When this hits the submission page, it runs the function and then blankpages when it's redirecting through the header. The header passes the GET again through the redirect with:

```
header("location: page.php?name=" . $name . "&number=" . $number);
```

The value being passed is using new lines within the text -

```
function selectvalue()
    {
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        var select = frm.browsers.value;
        if (select === "A")
            frm.message.value = "lineone\nlinetwo\nlinethree";
        else if (select === "B")
            frm.message.value = "lineone\nlinetwo\nlinethree";
        else
            frm.message.value = "lineone\nlinetwo\nlinethree";
    }
```

Submitting single lines works fine, only multiline messages. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: sooooo just strip out new lines $name and $number before triggering your redirect........  `s/\n//g`

Comment: I do need to keep the structure when it's passed through the redirect though, just stripping them out would mean lines would run directly into each other wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) to convert it into a valid URL